# Using with sns.set in seaborn plots

Tags: python, seaborn

I have searched for a clear answer to this and have not been able to find one, I apologize if this has been asked previously. I'm using seaborn 0.6 with matplotlib 1.4.3. I would like to temporarily change the styles of plots as I am creating many figures in an ipython notebook.

Specifically, in this example, I would like to change both the font size and the background style on a per-plot basis.

This creates the plot I am looking for but defines parameters globally:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=100)

sns.set(style="whitegrid", font_scale=1.5)
sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True);
```

however this fails:

```
with sns.set(style="whitegrid", font_scale=1.5):
    sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True);
```

with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-70c5b03f9aa8> in <module>()
----> 1 with sns.set(style="whitegrid", font_scale=1.5):
      2     sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True);

AttributeError: __exit__
```

I also tried:

```
with sns.axes_style(style="whitegrid", rc={'font.size':10}):
    sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True);
```

Which does not fail, however it also does not change the size of the font. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing in seaborn to do this but you could combine the dicts of parameters from `axes_style` and `plotting_context` and then pass them to `plt.rc_context`.

Comment: The with statement uses Python magic methods _\_enter_\_ and _\_exit_\_. Those methods are called by whatever sns.set is returning. It must have an _\_enter_\_ method, but not an _\_exit_\_ method. I think you may want to use a plotting context. http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.plotting_context.html#seaborn.plotting_context

Comment: `set` doesn't return anything; the relevant code is here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/rcmod.py#L69

Comment: mwaskom, thank you for your answer, I believe this is exactly what I was looking for. The `font_scale` parameter of the plotting context is not behaving as I would expect though. If I pass a dictionary to `plotting_context` I am able to change the font sizes of the plot, however passing an argument to `plotting_context` does not update the font sizes. There is an example of what I am referring to here.
[font_scale example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/johnchase/thesis_analysis/blob/master/Untitled.ipynb)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can stack context managers in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x = np.random.normal(size=100)
with sns.axes_style("whitegrid"), sns.plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=1.5):
    sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I was missing the "notebook" argument in the code I linked to above, which is why it did not seem to be working.

Comment: I was just playing with other ways to combine dictionaries and found [collections.ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects)... while it requires an import,  `with plt.rc_context(ChainMap(sns.axes_style('whitegrid'), sns.plotting_context('notebook', font_scale=1.5))):` .  It's also Python 3.3+ only according to the docs.  On 2.7 I'd prefer your stdlib solution above over a 3rd party lib for something so simple.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I am using, leveraging the context management provided by matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib

class Stylish(matplotlib.rc_context):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        matplotlib.rc_context.__init__(self)
        sns.set(**kwargs)
```

And then for instance:

```
with Stylish(font_scale=2):
    sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True)
```

Comment: Well, I had read the other answer but not the comments above... this is actually nothing particularly new, just copypastable.